# How to multiply each row of a matrix by corresponding column of another matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, multiplication

I have two matrices **A** and **B**. A is N-by-L matrix and B is L-by-N matrix.

```
A = [1 2 3;
     4 5 6];

B = [ 7   8;
      9  10;
     11  12];
```

I would like to multiply the each row of the first matrix by the corresponding column of the second matrix. After the multiplication I would have a (Nx1) vector. The result would be

```
C = [ 1*7 + 2*9  + 3*11,
      4*8 + 5*10 + 6*12];
```

I can perform the multiplication with a for loop, but it is not efficient for large matrices.

```
ASize = size(A);
for i = 1:ASize(1),
    C(i) = A(i,:) * B(:,i);
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
 C = sum(A.*B', 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work better and is simple

```
C=diag(A*B);
```